# WPF Datagrid events DataTriggers vs EventTriggers

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datatrigger, eventtrigger

relatively simple question that I am struggling to find a nice elegant solution to. I have a grid with a column that displays values that update every n seconds. I wish to show an animation when the value changes and flash the cell in different colours based on if the number is negative or positive. Found a whole host of methods that do almost what I want, but nothing that exactly matches my needs.

- Using an EventTrigger I can make a cell flash every time an update occurs. Using a relatively simple animation below. But I am unable to make the colour the animation uses conditional as the storyboard freezes the UI elements, so I cannot use binding in the storyboard to define the colour.

  ```
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Binding.TargetUpdated">
              <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose" Name="GreenCell">
                  <Storyboard TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                      <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.50" From="Green" To="Transparent" AutoReverse="False"/>
                  </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
  ```
- Using a DataTrigger I can make the cell colour conditional by creating a Converter that converts the updates to this Value and if the value is negative and then binding a data trigger to this and setting the background colour when this changes. But if the number is already negative, and remains negative (but changes) the trigger is not fired.

  ```
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource cellBackGroundConverter}}" Value="True">
              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose" Name="GreenCell">
                      <Storyboard TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                          <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.50" From="Green" To="Transparent" AutoReverse="False"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
              </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource cellBackGroundConverter}}" Value="False">
              <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard HandoffBehavior="Compose" Name="RedCell">
                      <Storyboard TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                          <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:1.50" From="Red" To="Transparent" AutoReverse="False"/>
                      </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
              </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          </DataTrigger>
  ```

What I require seems to be an event trigger, to capture every update and play the animation with the conditional aspect of the data trigger.

Surely I am missing something simple here, would love for someone to set me straight!

Many thanks

Matt